# php, preventing mysql injection by using gzcompress?

Tags: php, mysql

Would it be possible to prevent mysql injection using the gzcompress (and after retrieving it from the database, the gzuncompress) function? Or is there a reason why this would not work? Or is there a reason that this would not be a good idea at all?

Comment: AFAIK, the best way to prevent sql injection is to use command arguments instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea because

- Theoretically, there might be a sequence of data that, when compressed, leads to a SQL injection or simply breaks the query
- gzcompressed data can't be properly indexed and searched - you'll have a database full of garbled characters
- gzcompression is computationally expensive

simply always sanitize your data before entering it into a database, using the string escaping method of your library (like `mysql(i)_real_escape_string()`) or parametrized queries.

If you do that reliably, no further protection is necessary.

Comment: While the chance of compressed data leading to SQL *injection* is so low as to be virtually non-existent, there's the better chance that it'll simply break your SQL syntax. So you're back to escaping or binding values anyway. +1

Answer (score 1):

to protect against SQL Injection attacks, use PDO's parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection can be prevented 1 of 2 ways.  You can use parameterized queries or you can properly sanitize values when building your SQL statements.

Now, what you are suggesting will probably prevent *malicious* injections into the database, but that does not eliminate the possibility that will introduce SQL syntax errors (effectively SQL injection) into your SQL statements.

Also, by using compression functions, it will eliminate the possibility of viewing or searching the contents of the database without going through decompression.

This is a novel approach to avoiding SQL injection, but will cause you more problems than it actually solves.  You really need to stick with the tried and true solutions.

- [OWASP - SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
- [Steve Friedl's Unixwiz.net Tech Tips - SQL Injection Attacks by Example](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)
- [MSDN - SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx)